# dont go back link after log out from the system

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have authorisation on my page and when I'm log out from page I'm redirecting user to main page (`index.php`) for example, after this if user click back link in browser she/he can go and see cached pages which is available when user is logged in...

if I'll clean browser data manually it is not shows back pages ...
how can I clean the browser cash from javascript? Or any other better solution?

Comment: Use sessions with a token http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html

Comment: dont use javascript for this

Comment: it is not run on server page is loaded from browser cash... in server side i have session and destroy session ...

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP Sessions, If the user logout, hitting back button shouldnt take them to authenticated pages. so you have to handle sessions in a better way. check this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: as i sad it not make request to server it comes from browser cash ... -1